# drawImage with Canvas is sending image to the back of the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been doing a little experimenting with canvas, creating drawings using lines shapes text etc, and inserting .png files.  The inserting .png files is the bit that I cannot get to work.

Edit:
Undesired behaviour of this code: I load shapes to the graphics context, then load an image file to the graphics context, however when the graphics context is drawn, the image is at behind the shapes, despite being drawn last.
I wanted the image file to be at the top, in front of the shapes.

Desired behaviour:  To bring image file to the front of the canvas, so it is not hidden by shapes drawn in the graphics context.

```
function loadImage(name) {
    images[name] = new Image();
    images[name].src = "DogWalking/" + name + ".png";
    images[name].onload = function() {
        graphics.drawImage(this, 0, 300);
        canvas.bringToFront(this);
    };
}
```

the function for drawing is called here:

```
function draw() {
    graphics.save();  // to make sure changes don't carry over from one call to the next
    graphics.fillStyle = "transparent";  // background color
    graphics.fillRect(0,0,wWidth, wHeight);
    graphics.fillStyle = "black";
    applyLimits(graphics,xleft,xright,ytop,ybottom,true);
    graphics.lineWidth = pixelSize;

    world.draw(graphics);

    graphics.drawImage(images["dog-walking11"],200,200);

    graphics.restore();
}
```

code for the whole page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<title>Hierarchical Modeling 2D</title>
<style>
    #messagediv {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 0;
        background-color: indigo;
    }
        #canvasdiv {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rgbcolor.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    "use strict";
    var totalResources = 17;
    var numResourcesLoaded = 0;

var images = {};

function loadImage(name) {
  images[name] = new Image();
  images[name].src = "DogWalking/" + name + ".png";
  images[name].onload = function() { 
  //
  graphics.drawImage(this, 0, 300);
  canvas.bringToFront(this);
  }
}

    var canvas;    // DOM object corresponding to the canvas
    var graphics;  // 2D graphics context for drawing on the canvas
    var ctx;  // 2D graphics context for drawing on the canvas
    var myNumber = 0, myNumber2 = 0, myInterval,  myInterval2, myelement, thisdiv, printx;
    var mycoords = new Array();
    var pcoords = new Array(); //coordinates of the portal.
    //var pcoords = [[0,0], [50,300], [250,150]]; //coordinates of the portal.
    var nocoords = 2;
    var frameNumber = 0;  // Current frame number.
    var frameNumber2 = 0;
    var sun;
    var sun2;
    var ground;
    var world;
    var pixelSize;
    var wWidth;
    var wHeight;
    var portals = new Array("calendar1","alternativsearch","art1", "directory1");
    var portalsval = new Array();
    var portalsobj;
    var leftj = new Array(3,1,4,2);
    var forwards = "http://www.alternativworld.com";


    // ----------------  Set Page Layout  ----------------


// function to set size of canvas and location of portals       
function pageLayout() {

    var w = window, d = document, e = d.documentElement, g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    wWidth = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
    wHeight = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;

    // Adjust wWidth and wHeight if ratio does not match scenary 7 by 5.
    if (wWidth/wHeight != 7/5)
        if (wWidth/wHeight > 7/5) {
            var widthPortion = 5 * wWidth/wHeight;
            wWidth = wWidth * 7 / widthPortion;
        } else {
            var heightPortion = 7 * wHeight/wWidth;
            wHeight = wHeight * 5 / heightPortion;
        }

    var widthheight, localerror = false;
    widthheight = Math.min(wWidth, wHeight);

    if(widthheight < 400){
        var localerror = true;
    }

    if (localerror == true)
        alert("Warning, the page size of your browser or your screen resolution may be too small to correctly view this web page.");

    var theCanvas = d.getElementById("theCanvas");
    theCanvas.height = wHeight;
    theCanvas.width = wWidth;

}

//Function to listen to the mouse events and see if a link is selected.
function doMouseDown(evt) {
    var r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = Math.round(evt.clientX - r.left);
    var y = Math.round(evt.clientY - r.top);
alert(evt.clientX+ " " + evt.clientY);
    for (var i = portals.length+1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var p = pcoords[i];
        if (Math.abs(p[0] - x) <= 50 && Math.abs(p[1] - y) <= 50) {
            document.location.href = forwards;
            return;
        } else if (Math.abs(0 - x) <= 50 && Math.abs(0 - y) <= 50){
            document.location.href = "http://www.alternativeuk.co.uk";
            return;
        }
    }
}


    // ----------------  The object-oriented scene graph API  ------------------

    /**
     * The base class for all nodes in the scene graph data structure.
     */
    function SceneGraphNode() {
        this.fillColor = null;   // If non-null, the default fillStyle for this node.
        this.strokeColor = null; // If non-null, the default strokeStyle for this node.
    }
    SceneGraphNode.prototype.doDraw = function(g) {
            // This method is meant to be abstract and must be
            // OVERRIDDEN in any actual object in the scene graph.
            // It is not meant to be called; it is called by draw().
        throw "doDraw not implemented in SceneGraphNode"
    }
    SceneGraphNode.prototype.draw = function(g) {
           // This method should be CALLED to draw the object
           // represented by this SceneGraphNode.  It should NOT
           // ordinarily be overridden in subclasses.
        graphics.save();
        if (this.fillColor) {
            g.fillStyle = this.fillColor;
        }
        if (this.strokeColor) {
            g.strokeStyle = this.strokeColor;
        }
        this.doDraw(g);
        graphics.restore();
    }
    SceneGraphNode.prototype.setFillColor = function(color) {
            // Sets fillColor for this node to color.
            // Color should be a legal CSS color string, or null.
        this.fillColor = color;
        return this;
    }
    SceneGraphNode.prototype.setStrokeColor = function(color) {
            // Sets strokeColor for this node to color.
            // Color should be a legal CSS color string, or null.
        this.strokeColor = color;
        return this;
    }
    SceneGraphNode.prototype.setColor = function(color) {
            // Sets both the fillColor and strokeColor to color.
            // Color should be a legal CSS color string, or null.
        this.fillColor = color;
        this.strokeColor = color;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     *  Defines a subclass, CompoundObject, of SceneGraphNode to represent
     *  an object that is made up of sub-objects.  Initially, there are no
     *  sub-objects.
     */
    function CompoundObject() {
        SceneGraphNode.call(this);  // do superclass initialization
        this.subobjects = [];  // the list of sub-objects of this object
    }
    CompoundObject.prototype = new SceneGraphNode(); // (makes it a subclass!)
    CompoundObject.prototype.add = function(node) {
            // Add node a subobject of this object.  Note that the
            // return value is a reference to this node, to allow chaining
            // of method calls.
        this.subobjects.push(node);
        return this;
    }
    CompoundObject.prototype.doDraw = function(g) {
            // Just call the sub-objects' draw() methods.
        for (var i = 0; i < this.subobjects.length; i++)
            this.subobjects[i].draw(g);
    }

    /**
     *  Define a subclass, TransformedObject, of SceneGraphNode that
     *  represents an object along with a modeling transformation to
     *  be applied to that object.  The object must be specified in
     *  the constructor.  The transformation is specified by calling
     *  the setScale(), setRotate() and setTranslate() methods. Note that
     *  each of these methods returns a reference to the TransformedObject
     *  as its return value, to allow for chaining of method calls.
     *  The modeling transformations are always applied to the object
     *  in the order scale, then rotate, then translate.
     */
    function TransformedObject(object) {
        SceneGraphNode.call(this);  // do superclass initialization
        this.object = object;
        this.rotationInDegrees = 0;
        this.scaleX = 1;
        this.scaleY = 1;
        this.translateX = 0;
        this.translateY = 0;
    }
    TransformedObject.prototype = new SceneGraphNode();  // (makes it a subclass!)
    TransformedObject.prototype.setRotation = function(angle) {
           // Set the angle of rotation, measured in DEGREES.  The rotation
           // is always about the origin.
        this.rotationInDegrees = angle;
        return this;
    }
    TransformedObject.prototype.setScale = function(sx, sy) {
           // Sets scaling factors.
        this.scaleX = sx;
        this.scaleY = sy;
        return this;
    }
    TransformedObject.prototype.setTranslation = function(dx,dy) {
           // Set translation mounts.
        this.translateX = dx;
        this.translateY = dy;
        return this;
    }
    TransformedObject.prototype.doDraw = function(g) {
            // Draws the object, with its modeling transformation.
        g.save();
        if (this.translateX != 0 || this.translateY != 0) {
            g.translate(this.translateX, this.translateY);
        }
        if (this.rotationInDegrees != 0) {
            g.rotate(this.rotationInDegrees/180*Math.PI);
        }
        if (this.scaleX != 1 || this.scaleY != 1) {
            g.scale(this.scaleX, this.scaleY);
        }
        this.object.draw(g);
        g.restore();
    }

    /**
     *  A subclass of SceneGraphNode representing filled triangles.
     *  The constructor specifies the vertices of the triangle:
     *  (x1,y1), (x2,y2), and (x3,y3).
     */
    function Triangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3) {
        SceneGraphNode.call(this);
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
        this.x3 = x3;
        this.y3 = y3;
    }
    Triangle.prototype = new SceneGraphNode();
    Triangle.prototype.doDraw = function(g) {
        g.beginPath();
        g.moveTo(this.x1,this.y1);
        g.lineTo(this.x2,this.y2);
        g.lineTo(this.x3,this.y3);
        g.closePath();
        g.fill();
    }

    /**
     * Directly create a line object as a SceneGraphNode with a
     * custom doDraw() method.  line is of length 1 and
     * extends along the x-axis from (0,0) to (1,0).
     */
    var line = new SceneGraphNode();
    line.doDraw = function(g) {
        g.beginPath();
        g.moveTo(0,0);
        g.lineTo(1,0);
        g.stroke();
    }

    /**
     * Directly create a filled rectangle object as a SceneGraphNode with a
     * custom doDraw() method.  filledRect is a square with side 1, centered
     * at (0,0), with corners at (-0.5,-0.5) and (0.5,0.5).
     */
    var filledRect = new SceneGraphNode();
    filledRect.doDraw = function(g) {
        g.fillRect(-0.5,-0.5,1,1);
    }

    /**
     * Directly create a rectangle object as a SceneGraphNode with a
     * custom doDraw() method.  rect is a square with side 1, centered
     * at (0,0), with corners at (-0.5,-0.5) and (0.5,0.5).  Only the
     * outline of the square is drawn.
     */
    var rect = new SceneGraphNode();
    rect.doDraw = function(g) {
        g.strokeRect(-0.5,-0.5,1,1);
    }

    /**
     * Directly create a filled circle object as a SceneGraphNode with a
     * custom doDraw() method.  filledCircle is a circle with radius 0.5
     * (diameter 1), centered at (0,0).
     */
    var filledCircle = new SceneGraphNode();
    filledCircle.doDraw = function(g) {
        g.beginPath();
        g.arc(0,0,0.5,0,2*Math.PI);
        g.fill();
    }

    var clickHere = new SceneGraphNode();
    clickHere.doDraw = function(g) {
        g.fillText("click here :)",0,0)
    }

    /**
     * Directly create a circle object as a SceneGraphNode with a
     * custom doDraw() method.  filledCircle is a circle with radius 0.5
     * (diameter 1), centered at (0,0).  Only the outline of the circle
     * is drawn.
     */
    var circle = new SceneGraphNode();
    circle.doDraw = function(g) {
        g.beginPath();
        g.arc(0,0,0.5,0,2*Math.PI);
        g.stroke();
    }

    var dog = new SceneGraphNode();
    dog.doDraw = function(g) {
        g.drawImage(images["dog-walking11"],-2, 2);
        alert(images["dog-walking11"].name);
    }


    // -------------------- Specific to this application ----------------------------

    /*
     * Define two extra basic objects as SceneGraphNodes with custom doDraw() methods.
     * One represents the ground, the other a vane for a windmill.
     */
    var ground = new SceneGraphNode();
    ground.doDraw = function(g) {
        g.beginPath();
        g.moveTo(0,-1);
        g.lineTo(0,0.8);
        g.lineTo(1.5,1.65);
        g.lineTo(1.8,1.3);
        g.lineTo(3,2.1);
        g.lineTo(4.7,0.7);
        g.lineTo(6.1,1.2);
        g.lineTo(7,0.8);
        g.lineTo(7,-1);
        g.closePath();
        g.fill();
    }
    var windmillVane = new SceneGraphNode();
    windmillVane.doDraw = function(g) {
        g.beginPath();
        g.moveTo(0,0);
        g.lineTo(0.5,0.1);
        g.lineTo(1.5,0);
        g.lineTo(0.5,-0.1);
        g.closePath();
        g.fill();
    }

    var world;  // A SceneGraphNode representing the entire picture.  This should
                // be created in the createWorld() method.

    var pixelSize;  // The size of one pixel, in the transformed coordinates.
                    //    This is used as the default width of a stroke.

    var background = "#C8C8FF"; // A CSS color string giving the background color.
                                // the draw() function fills the canvas with this color.

    var xleft = 0;   // The requested xy-limits on the canvas, after the 
    var xright = 7;   //    coordinate transformation has been applied.
    var ybottom = -1; //    The transformation is applied in the draw() function.
    var ytop = 4;

    var frameNumber = 0;  // Current frame number.

    var cart;   // TransformedObjects that are animated.
    var wheel;
    var sun;
    var clickText1;
    var clickText2;
    var rotor;


    /**
     *  Create the scene graph data structure.  The global variable world must
     *  refer to the root node of the scene graph.  This function is called in
     *  the init() function.
     */
    function createWorld() {

    pageLayout();

        var i;
        var sunTemp = new CompoundObject();
        sunTemp.setColor("yellow"); // color for filled circle and light rays
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {  // add the 12 light rays, with different rotations
           sunTemp.add( new TransformedObject(line).setScale(0.75,0.75).setRotation(i*30) );
        }
        sunTemp.add( filledCircle );  // the face of the sun
        sunTemp.add( new TransformedObject(circle).setColor("#B40000") ); // outlines the face
        sun = new TransformedObject(sunTemp);

        clickText1 = new TransformedObject(clickHere).setColor("#B40000").setScale(0.01,-0.01);

        var wheelTemp = new CompoundObject();
        wheelTemp.setColor("black"); // color for all but one of the subobjects
        wheelTemp.add( new TransformedObject(filledCircle).setScale(2,2) );
        wheelTemp.add( new TransformedObject(filledCircle).setScale(1.6,1.6).setColor("#CCCCCC") );
        wheelTemp.add( new TransformedObject(filledCircle).setScale(0.4,0.4) );
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {  // add the 12 spokes
           wheelTemp.add( new TransformedObject(line).setRotation(i*30) );
        }
        wheel = new TransformedObject(wheelTemp);

        var cartTemp = new CompoundObject();
        cartTemp.setColor("red"); // color for the rectangular body of the cart
        cartTemp.add( new TransformedObject(wheel).setScale(0.8,0.8).setTranslation(1.5,-0.1) );
        cartTemp.add( new TransformedObject(wheel).setScale(0.8,0.8).setTranslation(-1.5,-0.1) );
        cartTemp.add( new TransformedObject(filledRect).setScale(5,2).setTranslation(0,1) ); // the body of the cart
        cart = new TransformedObject(cartTemp).setScale(0.3,0.3);
        clickText2 = new TransformedObject(clickHere).setColor("yellow").setScale(0.01,-0.01);

        var rotorTemp = new CompoundObject(); // a "rotor" consisting of three vanes
        rotorTemp.setColor( "#C86464" ); // color for all of the vanes
        rotorTemp.add( windmillVane );
        rotorTemp.add( new TransformedObject(windmillVane).setRotation(120) );
        rotorTemp.add( new TransformedObject(windmillVane).setRotation(240) );
        rotor = new TransformedObject(rotorTemp);

        var windmill = new CompoundObject();
        windmill.setColor("#E0C8C8"); // color for the pole
        windmill.add( new TransformedObject(filledRect).setScale(0.1,3).setTranslation(0,1.5) ); // the pole
        windmill.add( new TransformedObject(rotor).setTranslation(0,3) ); // the rotating vanes

        world = new CompoundObject();
        world.setColor("#00961E"); // color used for the ground only
        world.add(ground);
        //world.add( new TransformedObject(filledRect).setScale(7,0.8).setTranslation(3.5,0).setColor("#646496") ); // road
        //world.add( new TransformedObject(filledRect).setScale(7,0.06).setTranslation(3.5,0).setColor("white") ); // line in road
        world.add( new TransformedObject(windmill).setScale(0.6,0.6).setTranslation(0.75,1) );
        world.add( new TransformedObject(windmill).setScale(0.4,0.4).setTranslation(2.2,1.3) );
        world.add( new TransformedObject(windmill).setScale(0.7,0.7).setTranslation(3.7,0.8) );
        world.add( new TransformedObject(sun).setTranslation(5.5,3.3) );
        world.add( new TransformedObject(clickText1).setTranslation(5.25,3.3) );
        world.add( cart );
        world.add( clickText2 );

        //alert(2);


    }

    /**
     * This will be called before each frame is drawn.
     */
    function updateFrame() {
        frameNumber++;
        if (frameNumber>= 312){
            frameNumber = 0;
            frameNumber2 = 1;
            }

        cart.setTranslation(-3 + 13*(frameNumber % 300) / 300.0, 0);
        clickText2.setTranslation(-3.3 + 13*(frameNumber % 300) / 300.0, 0.25);
        if (typeof(pcoords[5]) != 'undefined') {
            pcoords[5][0] = (-3.3 + 13*(frameNumber % 300) / 300.0-xleft)*canvas.width / (xright-xleft);
            pcoords[5][1] = (0.25-ytop)*canvas.height / (ybottom-ytop);
            }

        wheel.setRotation(-frameNumber*3.1);
        sun.setRotation(-frameNumber);
        rotor.setRotation(frameNumber * 2.7);
    }


    // ------------------------------- graphics support functions --------------------------

    /**
      * Draw one frame of the animation.  Probably doesn't need to be changed,
      * except maybe to change the setting of preserveAspect in applyLimits().
      */
    function draw() {
        graphics.save();  // to make sure changes don't carry over from one call to the next
        graphics.fillStyle = "transparent";  // background color
        graphics.fillRect(0,0,wWidth, wHeight);
        graphics.fillStyle = "black";
        applyLimits(graphics,xleft,xright,ytop,ybottom,true);
        graphics.lineWidth = pixelSize;

world.draw(graphics);

graphics.drawImage(images["dog-walking11"],200,200);

        graphics.restore();
    }

    /**
     * Applies a coordinate transformation to the graphics context, to map
     * xleft,xright,ytop,ybottom to the edges of the canvas.  This is called
     * by draw().  This does not need to be changed.
     */
     //pcoords[0][0] = 
     //pcoords[0][1]=
function applyLimits(g, xleft, xright, ytop, ybottom, preserveAspect) {
    var width = canvas.width;   // The width of this drawing area, in pixels.
    var height = canvas.height; // The height of this drawing area, in pixels.
    var k = portals.length; 
    var j;
    var i = 0, widthheight, myradius;
    var localerror = false;
    if (pcoords.length < k) {
        while (portals[i]){

        j = i + 1;
        if (width > 100){
            var rWidth = width/(k + 1);
            rWidth= Math.floor(rWidth);
        } else {
            var lWidth = 0;
            var rWidth = 0;
        }

        if (height > 100){
            var bHeight = height/(k + 1);
            bHeight= Math.floor(bHeight);
        } else {
            var tHeight = 0;
            var bHeight = 0;
            }

        var myleft = leftj[i] * rWidth - 50;
        var mytop = j * bHeight - 50;

            pcoords[i]= new Array;
            pcoords[i][0] = myleft;
            pcoords[i][1] = mytop;

        i = i + 1;
        }
    }



    if (preserveAspect) {
        // Adjust the limits to match the aspect ratio of the drawing area.
        var displayAspect = Math.abs(height / width);
        var requestedAspect = Math.abs(( ybottom-ytop ) / ( xright-xleft ));
        var excess;
        if (displayAspect > requestedAspect) {
            excess = (ybottom-ytop) * (displayAspect/requestedAspect - 1);
            ybottom += excess/2;
            ytop -= excess/2;
         }
         else if (displayAspect < requestedAspect) {
            excess = (xright-xleft) * (requestedAspect/displayAspect - 1);
            xright += excess/2;
            xleft -= excess/2;
         }
    }
    var pixelWidth = Math.abs(( xright - xleft ) / width);
    var pixelHeight = Math.abs(( ybottom - ytop ) / height);
    pixelSize = Math.min(pixelWidth,pixelHeight);
    if (frameNumber == 4 || frameNumber == 5){
    pcoords.push([(5.25-xleft)*width / (xright-xleft),(3.3-ytop)*height / (ybottom-ytop)]);
    pcoords.push([(-3.3 + 13*(frameNumber % 300) / 300.0-xleft)*width / (xright-xleft), (0.25-ytop)*height / (ybottom-ytop)]);
    }
    g.scale( width / (xright-xleft), height / (ybottom-ytop) );
    g.translate( -xleft, -ytop );
   // if (frameNumber < 3)

}


    //------------------ Animation framework ------------------------------

    var animationTimeout = null; // A null value means the animation is off.
                                 // Otherwise, this is the timeout ID.

    function frame() {
           // Draw one frame of the animation, and schedule the next frame.
        updateFrame();
        draw();
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown, false);
        animationTimeout = setTimeout(frame, 33);
    }

    function setAnimationRunning(run) {
        if ( run ) {
            if (animationTimeout == null) {
                    // If the animation is not already running, start
                    // it by scheduling a call to frame().
                animationTimeout = setTimeout(frame, 33);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (animationTimeout != null) {
                    // If the animation is running, stop it by
                    // canceling the next scheduled call to frame().
                clearTimeout(animationTimeout);
            }
            animationTimeout = null; // Indicates that animation is off.
        }
    }

    //----------------------- initialization -------------------------------

    function init() {
        try {
        canvas = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
        if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
        canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
    }

            graphics = canvas.getContext("2d");
        }
        catch (e) {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML =
                "Sorry, this page requires canvas graphics, but<br>" +
                "it looks like your browser does not support it<br>" +
                "Reported error: " + e;
            return;
        }
        // add any other necessary initialization
        document.getElementById("animateCheck").checked = true; // Make sure box is checked!
        loadImage("dog-walking11");

        createWorld();
        setAnimationRunning(true);  // start the animation
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()" style="background-color: rgb(220,220,220)">
<div id="messagediv">
    <h2>Hierarchical Modeling Example</h2>

    <!-- For error reporting:  the contents of the noscript tag are
         shown only if JavaScript is not available.  The paragraph with
         id="message" is for reporting errors using JavaScript.-->
    <noscript><b>This page requires JavaScript, which is<br>
       not enabled in your browser.</b></noscript>
    <p id="message" style="color:red"></p>

    <p><input type="checkbox" id="animateCheck" onchange="setAnimationRunning(this.checked)">
         <label for="animateCheck">Run Animation</label>
    </p>
</div>  
<div id="canvasdiv">
<canvas id="theCanvas" width= "400" height= "300"
                style="background-color: transparent"></canvas>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had to use graphics.drawImage() after using graphics.restore().

Though I was trying to draw the image in the correct order (after), compared to drawing the rectangles, circles etc, the shapes did not come out of the buffer onto the page until after the restore function().

When I was calling drawImage, I assumed that it was loading it onto the buffered canvas with the rest of the things, ready to be drawn in the correct order, when in fact it was putting it straight onto the page.

It seems strange since it was being called with the graphics context, so I thought it would be added to the rest of the canvas graphics, but i appear to be wrong.